# How to install PHP in Mac? I have both new & old versions. :(

Tags: php, apache, macos, installation

I have just installed the latest PHP in my Mac OS X from entrophy.ch.

I set the /etc/apache/httpd.conf  like that:

```
LoadModule php5_lib local/php5/libphp5.so
```

Where local/php5/libphp5.so  is the latest one.

I have also started apache by :

```
apachectl restart
```

Then I run php.
in browser:  localhost/phpinfo.php   i get the latest version 5.3  that's good.
however, in command line, I'm still running the old 5.2.1 version.   What should I do to make the command line run the latest one?

Comment: What do you see when you type "which php" into Terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.2
sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

This assumes that your PHP 5.3 binary is at /usr/local/php5/bin/php and that your 5.2 binary was at /usr/bin/php

Comment: thanks. it works.  Just wondering, if I want to change the Path variable, how should I do it?

Comment: @murvinlai: To change the PATH variable, create/edit a file name `.profile` in your home folder. Put a line that reads something like `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin/php:$PATH`. You will have to restart Terminal to see the effect. Keep in mind that this is not a system-wide variable; it only affects your user account, and only when you are at the command prompt.

Comment: so, which one is the "home folder"?  the /usr/local/   or /Users/Myname

Comment: @murvinlai /Users/Myname. You can also go into terminal and type `echo ~` to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a superuser.com question, but you have added the directory containing the PHP 5.2.1 to your PATH variable.  You will need to either replace the old version completely with the new version or edit your path variable to no longer include the old location but to instead include the new location.